# Javascript. Append to blob

Tags: javascript, blob

Because BlobBuilder is deprecated, we have to use Blob, so instead of

```
var bb = new (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder)();
bb.append(data);
var blob = bb.getBlob();
```

We do

```
var blob = new Blob([data]);
```

That is ok, but what if I want to append Data to same blob more times? Something like:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    bb.append(" "+i);
}
```

How to do it without BlobBuilder? Thanks all!

Comment: The constructor for `Blob` takes an array, so you should probably hang on to a buffer and append to that, then create a new Blob from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to minitech♦!

You answer moved me to answer my question. So what you show is again working with a variable and at the end write it to blob. I wanted so said update a blob, or with other words append to blob. So you can do it on this way:

```
var blob = new Blob([],  {type: "text/plain"});
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    blob = new Blob([blob," "+i], {type: "text/plain"});
}
```

Here is Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yuM2N/111/

Comment: Creating 10 blobs just to update a single one seems like a waste of space.

Comment: Because the same blob is each time overwritten the garbage collector will free used space, thus shouldn't be a problem. In worst case it has to allocate space for 2 blobs at the same time while writing.

Comment: The blob is not overwritten, *the reference to it* is. Thus at one point both the original and new data have to coexist, and unless the engine can somehow figure out that the two blobs aren't used at the same time somewhere, or it combines the blob in a non-copying style, the data will be duplicated each time.

Comment: Exactly, I meant reference. And it has to keep 2 blobs at the same time while writing. I don't say it is optimal, but it will not keep all 10 blobs after operation is complete.

Comment: The issue is not only that it is not optimal, but it is also an anti-pattern, at least in most languages with immutable objects and references. It's true that modern JS engines can optimize things like appending to string with `+=` in a loop, but programming for a certain optimizer is still bad in my opinion (especially in the case of JavaScript which does not have a primary engine, unlike say C# or Java). There is no guarantee the engine will optimize blob copying, and there is no guarantee that GC will step in during the loop. Build on Ry-'s answer and start with `blob` in the array.

Answer (score 2):

`[data]` is an array of parts, so you can just append to an array:

```
var parts = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    parts.push(" " + i);
}

var blob = new Blob(parts);
```